# ActionBarSherlock + split action bar menu + items with "withText" doesn't show text. How to fix?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm using ActionBarSherlock and I'm trying to add an options menu to the ActionBar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_prev"
        android:title="@string/menu_previous"
        android:icon="@drawable/left_navigation"
        android:showAsAction="always|withText" />

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_next"
        android:title="@string/menu_next"
        android:icon="@drawable/right_navigation"
        android:showAsAction="always|withText" />

</menu>
```

The icons are 32x32 pixels in the drawable-mdpi directory.  When the ActionBar is split (portrait orientation), the icons show up but no text shows (plenty of room though).  Long-pressing the icon Toasts the title.  When the ActionBar is not split (landscape orientation), both the icons AND text show up as expected.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Menu, MenuInflater, and getSupportMenuInflater() are all using the ActionBarSherlock implementations.

The 'Application' in the manifest declares:

```
android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
```

What can I do to make it show the title of each item when in portrait orientation?

Edit:  Possibly relevant is that I'm running Android 4.0.4.

Comment: AFAIK, `withText` is a request, not a command, for ABS and the native action bar.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Android >= 3.0 ABS uses the system implementation of the actionbar, thus the behavior you see is correct. See @CommonsWare comment to the question as to why the behavior is that way.